# PHP getting value from table in HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to get the value of clicked letter in PHP.
For example if I click "A" in the HTML page, PHP should know that "A" is clicked.
Note: all values take to the same PHP page.

```
<td><a href="FilmeA-Z.php" name="A">A</td>
<td><a href="FilmeA-Z.php" name="B">B</td>
```

Comment: `<a href="FilmeA-Z.php?letter=a" name="A">A</a>` and then in php : `$_GET['letter']`. don't forget to close the `<a>` tag

Comment: There is an example of a clicked element here, hope it helps ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422248/php-get-button-post-value-when-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Just use $_GET in php page like :

```
$variable=$_GET['letter'];
echo $variable; // show "A"
```

In html  page change url like:

```
<td><a href="FilmeA-Z.php?letter=A" name="A">A</td>
```